# training neural net is reducing accuracy

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, object-detection-api

My ultimate goal is to get a neural net model that will look at live video feed and identify whether a person is holding a knife or some other utensil like a fork or a spoon.  I tried a couple of models pretrained on the COCO dataset and realized that models like faster_RCNN have incredibly high accuracy but they can't handle live video feed because it takes them several seconds to make each prediction.  On the other hand, models like SSD_mobilenet do really well with real time video, but have much lower accuracy for silverware specifically.

Because of this wanted to retrain a mobilenet model to have better accuracy for knives, so I created a subset of the COCO dataset with just the knives.  I used the below code taken from the tensorflow tutorial on retraining models:

```
import itertools
import os
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub

print("TF version:", tf.__version__)
print("Hub version:", hub.__version__)
print("GPU is", "available" if tf.test.is_gpu_available() else "NOT AVAILABLE")

module_selection = ("mobilenet_v2_100_224", 224) 
handle_base, pixels = module_selection
MODULE_HANDLE ="https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/{}/feature_vector/4".format(handle_base)
IMAGE_SIZE = (pixels, pixels)
print("Using {} with input size {}".format(MODULE_HANDLE, IMAGE_SIZE))

BATCH_SIZE = 32

data_dir = 'coco/knife_dataset2014'

datagen_kwargs = dict(rescale=1./255, validation_split=.20)
dataflow_kwargs = dict(target_size=IMAGE_SIZE, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                   interpolation="bilinear")

valid_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    **datagen_kwargs)
valid_generator = valid_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'coco/knife_dataset2014/val', subset="validation", shuffle=False, **dataflow_kwargs)

do_data_augmentation = False 
if do_data_augmentation:
  train_datagen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
      rotation_range=40,
      horizontal_flip=True,
      width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2,
      shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2,
      **datagen_kwargs)
else:
  train_datagen = valid_datagen
train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    'coco/knife_dataset2014/train', subset="training", shuffle=True, **dataflow_kwargs)

do_fine_tuning = False 

print("Building model with", MODULE_HANDLE)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    # Explicitly define the input shape so the model can be properly
    # loaded by the TFLiteConverter
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + (3,)),
    hub.KerasLayer(MODULE_HANDLE, trainable=do_fine_tuning),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(train_generator.num_classes,
                          kernel_regularizer=tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.0001))
])
model.build((None,)+IMAGE_SIZE+(3,))
model.summary()

model.compile(
  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=0.005, momentum=0.9), 
  loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True, label_smoothing=0.1),
  metrics=['accuracy'])

steps_per_epoch = train_generator.samples // train_generator.batch_size
validation_steps = valid_generator.samples // valid_generator.batch_size
hist = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=2, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
    validation_data=valid_generator,
    validation_steps=validation_steps).history

saved_model_path = "saved_knife_model"
tf.saved_model.save(model, saved_model_path)
```

when I run it, it prints:

```
GPU is NOT AVAILABLE
Using https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/feature_vector/4 with input size (224, 224)
Found 50 images belonging to 1 classes.
Found 2956 images belonging to 1 classes.
Building model with https://tfhub.dev/google/imagenet/mobilenet_v2_100_224/feature_vector/4
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
keras_layer (KerasLayer)     (None, 1280)              2257984   
_________________________________________________________________
dropout (Dropout)            (None, 1280)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 1)                 1281      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,259,265
Trainable params: 1,281
Non-trainable params: 2,257,984
```

and then it gets consistantly less accurate as it trains.  The trained model's accuracy seems to start at a different accuracy each time (sometimes 0.6, sometimes 0.2), and mostly goes down with each epoch.  A recent test had the accuracy start at 0.26 and by epoch 100 it was down to 0.22.  Does anyone have a clue as to what's happening here?

Comment: whats about training/valuation losses ? Are they falling ?

Comment: loss went from 1.9112e-04 to 1.5595e-04 and val_loss is about the same

Comment: @user3150635 maybe you need to provide part of your dataset, or it is nearly impossible to tell why the model is not working.

Comment: @meTchaikovsky how can I provide part of my dataset?  Should I just post an image from it?  How will that help?

Comment: You need to monitor both train and test scores/loss. First step is to ensure your model is capable of overfitting : remove all regularization & dropout, and ensure your train score can get very high. Next, if needed, add regularization to remove overfitting. Also, you should try with Adam optimizer, as it is less relying on its parameters than SGD.

Answer (score 0):

If your loss is going down as you train, but your accuracy is as well, then the model is likely over fitting to the training data and therefore getting less accurate on the validation data (so long as your training and validation data are separate, which they appear to--and should--be).

[Here's](https://elitedatascience.com/overfitting-in-machine-learning) a good article on how you can midigate this effect (just skip down to part 6 for how to prevent it).

If you use the pretrained faster_RCNN model you said was accurate but slow, you could try calculating the predictions with it on a GPU, which might make it fast enough to be usable.